# In a FRAME runtime, where is the metadata actually constructed?

Tags: metadata

I'm trying to figure out where in the runtime's codebase the metadata that describes it is constructed.

I've read all about the different versions of metadata and explored how they represent runtimes in the [frame metadata crate](https://github.com/paritytech/frame-metadata/blob/main/frame-metadata/src/v15.rs). I've also looked at how [scale-info](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-info) is used to attach compile-time type information. I believe I have a decent understanding of those aspects.

In the runtime code I see the metadata runtime api implemented like this:

```rust
impl sp_api::Metadata<Block> for Runtime {
    fn metadata() -> OpaqueMetadata {
        OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
    }
}
```

But where is this mysterious `metadata` method defined? The [rustdocs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/node_template_runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.metadata) don't give too many clues.

Ultimately, I want to understand how the runtime synthesizes all the information from the pallets into a single piece of metadata.

Answer (score 1):

It follows this path.

- [`construct_runtime!`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/133157a54d6602981b8a7a40c70da28b7cc60716/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/mod.rs#L266)

  - [`expand_runtime_metadata`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/133157a54d6602981b8a7a40c70da28b7cc60716/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/metadata.rs#L24)

    - expand each item

---

For more detail about the items, check the `pallet` macro.

E.G. [pallet calls metadata](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/133157a54d6602981b8a7a40c70da28b7cc60716/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/call.rs#LL410C8-L410C8)